# Mockito with dexmaker on Android - getting a Virtual machine error mocking an activity

Tags: android, mockito, dalvik, dexmaker

Trying to do a partial mock of an activity using Mockito.spy after its instrumented on the Android VM (Emulator 4.1). Here is the error I get

```
java.lang.VirtualMachineError
at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(Native Method)
at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:207)
at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClass(DexFile.java:196)
at dalvik.system.DexClassLoader.findClass(DexClassLoader.java:226)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at com.google.dexmaker.stock.ProxyBuilder.loadClass(ProxyBuilder.java:272)
at com.google.dexmaker.stock.ProxyBuilder.buildProxyClass(ProxyBuilder.java:254)
at com.google.dexmaker.mockito.DexmakerMockMaker.createMock(DexmakerMockMaker.java:54)
at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:26)
at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:49)
at org.mockito.Mockito.spy(Mockito.java:1324)
at com.company.droid.helper.ActivitySandbox.setupActivity(ActivitySandbox.java:21)
at com.company.droid.ui.fragment.signup.SignupFragmentTest.setUp(SignupFragmentTest.java:50)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:529)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1448)
```

I've tried changing VMs, Mockito versions, Dexmaker versions but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you look in your log for any messages coming from Dalvik, especially at install or app startup time? You will generally get a bunch of spew that indicates (perhaps cryptically) a bit more detail about the problem.

Comment: I've recently switched from instrumentation tests to junit in pair with robolectric library. About spying - my observation it's usually issue with design.

Comment: Tracking here: https://code.google.com/p/dexmaker/issues/detail?id=9

Comment: Looks like they included the fix in DexMaker 1.1, which was released this March. While the jars (`dexmaker-1.1` and `dexmaker-mockito-1.1`) are not currently hosted on the Google Code site, the site has links at the bottom to download them from the Maven repository.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a bug in Dalvik, which is not being avoided by DexMaker.

See this bug report and vote for it if you want.
https://code.google.com/p/dexmaker/issues/detail?id=9