# Cannot Mock WebView with Mockito

Tags: android, testing, mocking, android-webview, mockito

I am using Mockito to mock classes for Android testing. It behaves as expected when mocking any given class, except WebView (as far as I have seen in my code). When attempting to mock a WebView using:

```
mock(WebView.class);
```

I receive the following stacktrace:

```
java.lang.VirtualMachineError
at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(Native Method)
at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:211)
at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:305)
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:62)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
at com.google.dexmaker.stock.ProxyBuilder.loadClass(ProxyBuilder.java:272)
at com.google.dexmaker.stock.ProxyBuilder.buildProxyClass(ProxyBuilder.java:254)
at com.google.dexmaker.mockito.DexmakerMockMaker.createMock(DexmakerMockMaker.java:56)
at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:26)
at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:51)
at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1243)
at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1120)
at com.ncsa.clientrms.navigation.WebFragment2Test.setUp(WebFragment2Test.java:19)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:190)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:175)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1661)
```

I have looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939655/mockito-with-dexmaker-on-android-getting-a-virtual-machine-error-mocking-an-ac), which might indicate these two situations stem from the same bug, especially since the stack traces are nearly identical. Is there something I can do to resolve this?

On a side note, is Mockito being maintained? I would rather not be tied to a dependency from 2012.

Comment: Make sure the import is android.webkit

Comment: `import android.webkit.WebView;`

Comment: Yes, Mockito does have a small team of developers working on it (http://code.google.com/p/mockito/people/list).  I don't know when the next release will be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having a similar issue on creating mocks using mockito for classes derived from FrameLayout and also for those from GridView.

As per the comment on the other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939655/mockito-with-dexmaker-on-android-getting-a-virtual-machine-error-mocking-an-ac) you mentioned, this issue has been fixed in version 1.1 of dexmaker and dexmaker-mockito.

These libs can be downloaded [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.dexmaker/dexmaker/1.1) and included in your libs directory. Just be sure to clean and rebuild to ensure that updated version 1.1 libs are used. I have seen issues where Android Studio was still picking up the previous versions of the libs. A manual delete of the bin folders in my project resolved this.